# Where are comparisons in java sorting methods?

Tags: java, sorting, methods

Question: Where are comparisons being made in each separate sorting method?
Also if you know please tell me which method count numbers are wrong and where to place my counters instead.trying to understand where and how many times sorting methods make comparisons.

```
Method        A        B   
Selection    4950     4950 
Bubble        99      9900 
Insertion     99      5049
Merge         712     1028
Shell         413      649
Quick        543      1041
```

Okay so to explain some parts, basically Array A is an array from 1-100 in ascending order. So this should be the minimum number of comparisons.
Array B is 100-1 in descending order. So I believe it should be the maximum number of comparisons. Array C is just randomly generated numbers, so it changes every time.

I feel like my selection and bubble sorts were counted correctly. Feel free to let me know where comparisons are being made that I haven't counted, or if I'm counting wrong comparisons.

Side note: Made some global variable to count the methods that were recursive in multiple sections.

```
class Sorting
   {
      static int[] X = new int[100];
      static int mergecount = 0;
      static int quickcount = 0;
      public static void selectionSort(int list[])
      {
         int count = 0;
         int position = 0, n = list.length;
         for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
         {
            position = j;
            for(int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
            {
               count++;
               if(list[k] < list[position])
                  position = k;
            }
            Swap(list, j, position);
         }
         System.out.println("counter" + count);
      }

  public static void Swap(int list[], int j, int k)
  {
     int temp = list[j];
     list[j] = list[k];
     list[k] = temp;
  }

  public static void bubbleSort(int list[])
  {
     int count = 0;
     boolean changed = false;
     do
     {
        changed = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++)
        {
           count++;
           if(list[j] > list[j + 1])
           {
              Swap(list, j, j+1);
              changed = true;
           }
        }
     } while(changed);
     System.out.println("counter" + count);
  }

  public static void insertionSort(int list[])
  {
     int count = 0;
     for(int p = 1; p < list.length; p++)
     {
        int temp = list[p];
        int j = p;
        count++;
        for( ; j > 0 && temp < list[j - 1]; j = j-1)
        {
           list[j] = list[j - 1];
           count++;
        }
        list[j] = temp;
     }
     System.out.println("counter" + count);
  }

  public static void mergeSort(int list[])
  {
     mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
     System.out.println("counter" + mergecount);
  }

  public static void mergeSort(int list[], int first, int last)
  {
     if(first < last)
     {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, first, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid + 1, last);
        Merge(list, first, mid, last);
     }

  }

  public static void Merge(int list[], int first, int mid, int last)
  {
     int count = 0;
     int first1 = first, last1 = mid;
     int first2 = mid + 1, last2 = last;
     int temp[] = new int[list.length];
     int index = first1;

     while(first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2)
     {
        if(list[first1] < list[first2])
        {
           temp[index] = list[first1++];
           mergecount++;
        }
        else
           temp[index] = list[first2++];
        index++;
        mergecount++;
     }

     while(first1 <= last1)
        temp[index++] = list[first1++];

     while(first2 <= last2)
        temp[index++] = list[first2++];

     for(index = first; index <= last; index++)
        list[index] = temp[index];


  }

  public static void shellSort(int list[])
  {
     int count = 0;
     int n = list.length;
     for(int gap = n / 2; gap > 0; gap = gap == 2 ? 1: (int) (gap/2.2))
        for(int i = gap; i < n; i++)
        {
           int temp = list[i];
           int j = i;
           count++;
           for( ; j >= gap && (temp < (list[j - gap])); j -= gap)
           {
              list[j] = list[j - gap];
              count++;
           }

           list[j] = temp;
        }
     System.out.println("counter" + count);
  }

  public static void quickSort(int start, int finish, int list[])
  {
     int count = 0;
     int left = start, right = finish, pivot, temp;
     pivot = list[(start + finish) / 2];
     do
     {
        while(list[left] < pivot)
        {
           left++;
           quickcount++;
        }

        while(pivot < list[right])
        {
           right--;
           quickcount++;
        }

        if(left <= right)
        {
           temp = list[left];
           list[left++] = list[right];
           list[right--] = temp;
           quickcount++;
        }
     }  while(left < right);

     if(start < right)
        quickSort(start, right, list);


     if(left < finish)
        quickSort(left, finish, list);

  }

  public static void copy(int list[])
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        X[i] = list[i];
  }

  public static void restore(int list[])
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        list[i] = X[i];
  }

  public static void displayArray(int list[])
  {
     for(int k = 0; k < list.length; k++)
        System.out.print(list[k] + " ");
     System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     int[] A = new int[100];
     for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        A[i] = i + 1;

     int[] B = new int[100];
     int q = 100;
     for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
        B[i] = q--;

     int[] C = new int[100];
     for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i++)
        C[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1); 

     displayArray(A);
     copy(A);
     selectionSort(A);
     displayArray(A);
     restore(A);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: Oh sorry, the question is if my comparison counters for array A and B are correct. so I suppose a code review yes but only for the counters.

Answer (score 1):

Note that QuickSort performance is greatly influenced by your choice of the pivot. With both of your test arrays sorted (ascending / descending) and because you are picking pivot as array[length/2] you are actually always picking the best pivot. So your test case B won't generate maximum number of comparisons for quicksort. If you were picking array[0] as pivot you'd get maximum number of comparisons for test case A and B.

The easiest way to count comparisons is to use a compare function and do it in there.

```
static int compareCount = 0;
int compareInt(int a, int b) {
    compareCount++;
    return a - b; // if 0 they are equal, if negative a is smaller, if positive b is smaller
}
```

Now just use compareInt in all your algorithms and you'll get an accurate count. You'll have to reset compareCount between each run though.