# Java Insertion Sort: Counting Data Comparisons

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to place a counter for number of data comparisons and number of data swaps of this insertion sort algorithm using Java. While I believe counter swapsNo is correctly placed, compsNo is not giving me the expected output (both initialized at zero). I originally placed it where it is currently to count in cases where compElem is compared to list item, but clearly this simply Ups the counter for each item in the list. I am wondering if the counter should perhaps occur twice in the algorithm or somewhere else completely.

```
public void insertionSort(T[] list, int length)
{
 for (int firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < length;
                               firstOutOfOrder ++)
 {
     Comparable<T> compElem =
               (Comparable<T>) list[firstOutOfOrder];
     compsNo++;

     if (compElem.compareTo(list[firstOutOfOrder - 1]) < 0)
     {
         Comparable<T> temp =
                     (Comparable<T>) list[firstOutOfOrder];
         //or perhaps compsNo++; should go here??
         int location = firstOutOfOrder;

         do
         {
             list[location] = list[location - 1];
             location--;
             swapsNo++;

         }
         while (location > 0 &&
                temp.compareTo(list[location - 1]) < 0);

         list[location] = (T) temp;

     }
   }
 }
```

Update: I've added an incrementation for compsNo++ within a while loop (previously doWhile) and incrementation for swapsNo++ within if statement. This is approaching the expected output, but I'm not yet confident in my edits.

```
public void insertionSort(T[] list, int length)
{
 for (int firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < length;
                               firstOutOfOrder ++)

 {
     Comparable<T> compElem =
               (Comparable<T>) list[firstOutOfOrder];
     compsNo++;
     if (compElem.compareTo(list[firstOutOfOrder - 1]) < 0)
     {
         Comparable<T> temp =
                     (Comparable<T>) list[firstOutOfOrder];

         int location = firstOutOfOrder;



         while (location > 0 && temp.compareTo(list[location - 1]) < 0)
         {
             compsNo++;

             list[location] = list[location - 1];
             location--;
             swapsNo++;
         }




         list[location] = (T) temp;
         swapsNo++;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: My advice would be to create a counting `Comparator`, and keep count in that class.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I originally tried something in line with ideas presented in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292615/where-are-comparisons-in-java-sorting-methods?rq=1, but as a beginner to Java I wasn't sure how to adapt it to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the comparations, you should increment `compsNo` just after or before every line that contains an invocation to `compareTo`.

In your code, you have two invocations to `compareTo`, and only one `compsNo++`.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my code to reflect an increment of compsNo in the do while loop. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, the doWhile will always execute at least once, and that could produce no comparations in case location==0. But the counter is going to be incremented anyway.

Comment: Also, I put the first compsNo++ before the if statement, because I figured it would be compared no matter what for each item in list. Is this correct, or should it be counted only if the comparesTo < 0?

Comment: The first compsNo++ is ok. The second is wrong, for the reason I wrote before.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm wondering why the doWhile still would increment if location==0 if the while condition is 'while (location > 0 && temp.compareTo(list[location - 1]) < 0);'

Comment: A do-while statement always executes at least once. A while statement instead, may never be executed in case the condition is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help, by the way. Would the embedded if statement (in edits) do the trick in this case?

Comment: I think you'd better use a while instead of a do-while

Comment: I seem to get the same output from a while statement as the doWhile. The difference between my swapsNo++ and compsNo++ is about the size of n (whereas expected output has a difference of about 20 between the two), so I'm still unsure if the counter is being incremented too many times?